# Plot a column for x versus another column in y, group by certain index in R

Tags: r, group-by, plot, ggplot2

I'm writing a program in R. I have a dataset like this:

```
  category  x-value y-value 
         1        2       5
         1        3       1
         1        4       10
         1        5       23
         2        2       12
         2        3       15
         2        4       21
         2        5       29
         3        2       34
         3        3       45
         3        4       7
         3        5       9
```

And I want to find a simple way to group the data by "category" and plot these 3 sets of data on a single xyplot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`?
Something like this?

```
df = read.table(text = "
category  x-value y-value 
     1        2       5
     1        3       1
     1        4       10
     1        5       23
     2        2       12
     2        3       15
     2        4       21
     2        5       29
     3        2       34
     3        3       45
     3        4       7
     3        5       9", header = TRUE, sep = "")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x.value, y.value, colour = factor(category))) + geom_point() +
  geom_path()
```

[image]

OR this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x.value, y.value, shape = factor(category), 
colour = factor(category))) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very neat :). Originally I tried to use subset() to divide the dataset, but this was not as neat as the way you provide. Still learning how to plot beautiful graphs with ggplot.

Comment: @sprite728 You might like to read [wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/)